# Create radio boxes that have a relationship to a dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have some json data:
*Notice that the sizes are a big string not an array*

```
$scope.productData = {
colors_and_sizes: {
  data: {
    Black:
      {
       sizes: "X Small, Small, Medium, Large, Xlarge, XX Large"
      }
    Blue:
      {
       sizes: "X Small, Small, Medium, Large, Xlarge, XX Large"
      }
   }
 }

 }
```

and some html:

```
<form>
<div class="color-pick" ng-repeat="(key, val) in productData.colors_and_sizes.data">
  <input type="radio" ng-model="myColor" ng-value="{{key}}"/>
  <div class="size-pick">
    <!-- it's weird cuz the sizes are a big string? how to set ng-options" -->
    <select ng-model="mySize" ng-options=""></select>
  </div>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: Alright, so what's the question? What's the problem? What have you already tried?

Comment: You didn't ask any question...

Comment: @Matthew take a look at my answer, i guess that is what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually i guess what you is trying to ask is that, You are having a String for the key sizes, which you wants to populate within the `ng-options` with a radio button

If that is what Just take a look at this.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nidhishkrishnan/z8wzkojf/)**

**html**

```
<div class="color-pick" ng-repeat="(key, val) in productData.colors_and_sizes.data">
        <input type="radio" name="colors" ng-model="myColor" ng-value="{{key}}" />{{key}}
        <div class="size-pick">
            <select ng-model="mySize" ng-options="size for size in val.sizes.split(',')"></select>
        </div>
</div>
```

Also one more thing i want to say is that the json which you have shown is not correct, It should be like as shown below

```
{
  "colors_and_sizes": {
    "data": {
      "Black": {
        "sizes": "X Small, Small, Medium, Large, Xlarge, XX Large"
      },
      "Blue": {
        "sizes": "X Small, Small, Medium, Large, Xlarge, XX Large"
      }
    }
  }
}
```